# Using AFHTTPClient with Cookie authentication

Tags: ios, cocoa, authentication, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

My app pulls data from a website which uses Form based authentication. It needs to transparently react to a redirection to the login page & provide the requested credentials via a POST request.

I've previously used ASIHTTPREQUEST & then gone through a process of checking the url to see if I've been redirected to the authentication page & if so sending the POST request with the login form variables & then making the original request again. It works but is a bit of a hack.

I'm presently moving my code over to AFNetworking & wondering if there is a more elegant way of achieving this, perhaps injecting an auth header? to get AFHTTPClient to trigger the authentication delegate methods when a redirect to the auth page occurs & then posting the form. Here's a bit of pseudo code:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
if ([Connection isAuthURL:[request url]])
{
    // If so have we just tried to login ?
    if ( requestState == requestStateSendingLoginCredentials )
    {
        // Login Failed - tried to login & been redirected back to login page
        [self requestFailed:request];
    }
    else
    {
        // We have been directed to login page after a page request
        requestState = requestStateSendingLoginCredentials
        [self postLoginForm:request];
    }
}
else 
{ // Not the authentication page
    if ( requestState == requestStateSendingLoginCredentials )
    {   // We must have successfully logged in
        requestState = requestStateSuccessful;
        // If it was a form we need to post again now were logged in.
        if ([lastRequest isAForm])
        {
            // If original request that triggered the login was a POST request
            // we have to re-send it.
            [self requestURL:nil]; // This will send the last request again
            return;
        }
    }
    if (requestState == requestStateSuccessful)
    {
        [self processResponse:request];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make things easy on yourself and use what HTTP gives you.

HTTP defines [status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) that tell you whether a request was successful (200) or if they require authorization (401).

Store your credentials in an `Authorized` [HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for your shared `AFHTTPClient` instance, and you'll be authenticated for all subsequent calls.

Or, if those aren't doing it, you can use `AFURLConnection -setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:` to respond to authentication challenges.

Comment: Problem is I don't get a 401 for authentication. I get a 200 after redirecting to the login page. How could I get the `AFURLConnection -setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:` to fire when this occurs?

Comment: Well, the authentication callbacks only work if the server sends any indication that authentication is supposed to happen. Maybe you can hook into the redirect by providing a hook, using the [just-added redirect response block property](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/d17b2998d7d7c877a3133959c97498780e064681).

Comment: Either way, since if you have any ability to change the server backend or use a proper API instead, that would make things much, much easier.

Comment: Thanks mattt, I can't touch server so I'll try playing with the redirect response block.